# How to make disabled button after some amount of clicks

Tags: javascript

I have tried to disable my button once the user has clicked a button three times, using the following code:

```
var count = 0;
function clickFunc() {
    count += 1;
    var click = document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = count;
    var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
}

if(count >= 3) {

    btn.disabled = true;
}
```

Why is my `btn.disabled = true;` statement never executed?

Comment: Move it inside the function and it will work.

Comment: @MinusFour oh Thank You! But why it doesn't work oustside the function? It may be cause the btn is local variable and  it's not working outside the function?

Comment: Because, outside the function it's just executed once. Where as inside the function it gets executed every time there's a click.

Comment: @Viktor it doesn't work because that piece of code will never execute. `if(count >= 3)` will be executed only once, when count is `0`. You need to execute that code every time someone clicks, and for that you need it to be inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the `if` statement inside the `clickFunc()`, it will be called every time the button is clicked and check it at that time. When writing code, try to run through it in your mind.  `If` statements should be placed where they make the most logical sense.

```
var count = 0;
function clickFunc() {
count += 1;
var click = document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = count;
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

if(count >= 3) 
     btn.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 0;
function clickFunc() {
    count += 1;
    var click = document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = count;
    var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    if(count >= 3) {
        btn.disabled = true;
    }
}
clickFunc();
clickFunc();
clickFunc();
```

In the third call it will be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var count=0;

 //called when button is clicked.
 function clickFunc() {
count += 1;
 //lets say id of button is btn
 if(count>3){
 $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
 }
}


});
```

or you can just move the if statement inside the function.

Hope that was any helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var count = 0;
function clickFunc() {
  count += 1;
  var click = document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = count;
  var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
  if(count >= 3) { // placed inside the click function
    btn.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="clicks">0</div>
<br/>
<button class="btn" onclick="clickFunc()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to use it as a simple module? Are you using jQuery?

HTML

```
<body>
    <button>Click!</button>
</body>
```

JS

```
var myCounter= (function() {
    var clicksleft= 3;

    var startCount= function(onFinish) {
        var me= this;
        clicksleft = clicksleft - 1;

        if(clicksleft===0) {
            onFinish();
        }
    };

    return {
        startCount: startCount
    }
})();


jQuery(function ($) {
    $('button').click(function() {
        myCounter.startCount(function() {
            $('button').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(function(){
   var count = 3,
    $btn = $('input[type="submit"]'); //Or which ever you want
    //Change the label of $btn
    $btn.val($btn.val()+' ('+count+')')
    
   $btn.click(function(){
    $btn.val($btn.val().replace(count,count-1));
    count--;
    if(count==0) {
    return !$btn.attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
   })
 })
 </script>
 <title>Javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
 <input type="submit" value="Test">
</body>
</html>
```